# why am I getting unexpected token error in react project in header.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Working on a small training project , and I keep getting syntax error which I do not understand. Please see the errors below:

```
./src/components/Header.js
SyntaxError: E:\REACT_APP\drf_project\src\components\Header.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (40:7)

  38 | }
  39 | 
> 40 | Export default Header;
     |        ^
  41 |
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/ Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/ Typography';
import CssBaseLine from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseLine';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/Styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
                appBar: {
                  borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
                },
}));

function Header() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseLine />
        <AppBar

          Position='static'
          Color='white'
          Elevation={0}
          className={classes.appBar}
        >

          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant='6' color='inherit' noWrap>
              BlogmeUp
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>

        </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Export default Header;
```

I keep looking for the root cause, yet no success, though I am following exactly the way its been shown in a tutorial. Could you please let me know the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use comma `,`

```
 </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Please disregard the previous error, I had already sorted it out. I have updated the original post with new errors

Comment: `export default Header` It's just a typo

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma outside your React.Fragment tag.

Change `</React.Fragment>,` to `</React.Fragment>`

and also Export should be lowercase in `Export default Header` that is `export default Header`

Comment: Thank you, this thread can be concluded. Have a nice day